# SVN restrict the file so that only defined user may modify it

Tags: svn, locking

I have a SVN repo on which 100 people are currently working. There is one file where I have to limit the write access, so that only tree defined user can un-/lock the file.

Is there a possibility to setup this access restrictions?

Comment: This seems like a really strange request. What's your goal? Are you trying to restrict the file so that only one user can *modify* it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure [pre-lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-lock.html) and [pre-unlock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-unlock.html) hook scripts on the repository.